# MySQL does't return all rows

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL WorkBench 6.1 and I have 139 rows at one table.

If I do:

```
Select * from table
```

It only returns the first 111 rows, but if I do:

```
Select * from table where idRow = 139
```

It returns the row 139, which is correct.

Any ideas of what is going on?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the table

```
create table OrderLines
(
    idOrder int references Orders,
    idLine int primary key,
    q int ,
);
```

Until now idOrder = 139 and idLine = 1262

Comment: "and I have 139 rows at one table" --- how do you know that?

Comment: because the last order that i have made corresponds to the number 139

Comment: that's not true. It just means there is a row that has the value of `idRow` column that equals to `139`. And it might be the single row in your table.

Comment: do a 'select count(*) from table;' and check how many rows are actually there, a id itself says nothing.

Comment: @Martin your latest update confuses me, how can you add idRow = 139 to the WHERE clause if idRow doesn't exist in your DDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have 139 actual rows and not just the last auto increment id is 139 - meaning some rows could have been deleted?

You can confirm the total number of rows by running

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
```

If this returns, 139 you are indeed missing some, this isn't the fault of `SELECT * FROM table` as this will return every row.  Maybe the tool you're using is limiting the number of rows returned. This is actually quite common, most tools will do this to prevent loading a huge amount of data, however 111 is a very small and odd number.

Comment: Hi did what you said and i have 1262

Comment: @Martin if `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` returns 1262, then you have 1,262 rows in your table. `SELECT * FROM table` will return all 1,262 rows, if you're only seeing 111 of them then something else is appending `LIMIT 111` to your query, or just showing you the first 111 rows.  Either profile the query to check for a LIMIT clause or try another MySQL client

Comment: the problem where in the select limit. It was at 1000 rows. When the idOrder = 139 the idLine = 1000. I have changed the limit to 50000 and mysql shows all the rows. Thanks